# Bug in job listings

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

All job listings have the following:

```
Html.RenderPartial(MVC.Jobs.Views.SuggestionsSidebar, Model.SuggestedJobs);
```

Located at the bottom right side of the page after the listing / ad.

Comment: Confirmed - will get this fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhhh, this should be fixed with the next build.

*Someone* (me)  removed an `if` condition in a razor template a tad too fast.

Thanks for the report!